# The Wi-fi on my UMDIGI keeps switching off on its own

Tags: wi-fi

The Wi-fi on my UMDIGI keeps switching off on its own. 
i have checked the setting and seems normal.
all work colleagues have the same problem and the problem started at the same time !

Comment: Did you check with the workplace IT/ resources admin ?

Comment: If everyone around has the same problem, it's rather not an Android issue but something with the router. As @beeshyams pointed out, you'd better contact your IT staff on this – we won't be able to help out.

Comment: Thank you. the same issue happens at home too, this eliminates the rooter option.